# SQLAlchemy ORM Many-to-Many table relationship - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I am currently trying to loop through some JSON data I have loaded and use SQLAlchemy's ORM to insert that data in my MySQL server.

I have created a class that reflects my tables and the corresponding columns, and I am running into a unique error when creating an instance of that class

i.e. `cow = Dataset_Table()`

I have double checked that my models are being imported correctly and that they are available where I am creating that object.

But I keep getting: 
`File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Table' and 'Table'`

I thought that it was because I was not giving the class the information it is required (id, name, etc) but even if I create a "dummy" table with a dummy class, and nothing is required, the instantiation of that class still spits out that error above.

I'm going to attach my model and maybe you see something I am missing.

Thank you!

```
class Dataset_Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dataset'

    dataset_id = Column(INTEGER(10), primary_key=True)
    dataset_name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    dataset_title = Column(String(45))
    dataset_comment = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    dataset_is_archived = Column(TINYINT(4), nullable=False, server_default=text("'0'"))
    Dataset_date_created = Column(TIMESTAMP)

tables = relationship('Table', secondary='dataset - table')
```

Comment: Looks like the error is related to your `tables = relationship('Table', secondary='dataset - table')` line. The `secondary` parameter should be set to whatever variable you have assigned your association table to (not set to a string value).

Comment: Thank you! I believe this was it (although I ran into another error) Thanks!!

Comment: @benvc A string value is fine, but is evaluated as Python during mapper configuration, in a namespace containing tables, models, and SQLA constructs. Hence the error with the subtraction. In other words the string should represent a table name, a `join()` construct, or such. For example `'dataset.select().except_(table.select())'` would in theory be a valid secondary (in the spirit of the subtraction)

Comment: @IljaEverilä - thanks for the clarification. So it sounds like the `secondary` parameter can be a reference to an object or to a string that references a table or a valid query construct.